# Multiple connections to the same DB in the same TransactionScope

Tags: c#, transactions

How are the connections handled in a single transaction when we open close connections for each statement in C#?

The scenario is with the **same connection string** and the connection is opened and closed multiple types, once for every statement.

Consider the following example

```
void updateSomething() {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(  
      "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))  
    {  
        connection.Open();        
        // Execute the statements
        connection.Close();  
    }  
 }
```

When I'm executing the following code:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            this.updateSomething();
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

The recommendation is to use a connection Open/Close for each statement. That is because we are not actually creating connections, we are just using one from the pool.

Why is this the case? I get it that we hold the connection for as little time as we can, but the thing is that in most transactions, we are going to get it in the next moment during the next statement.

Is it only to avoid the demanding code computation time in between the statements if some such exists (which it shouldn't as it would lock the database in the transaction state for much longer that needed).

Wouldn't it make sense to keep one connection open for the duration of the transaction?

Comment: *"The recommendation is to use a connection Open/Close for each statement"* - Where did you read that? (I'm not doubting it, I'm just curious)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query

Comment: Spoilers: one connection actually *is* kept open for the duration of the transaction, because transactions cannot actually span connections (unless you involve the Distributed Transaction Coordinator). This is transparently taken care of for you by `SqlConnection`, which recognizes this situation if you reuse the exact same connection string. The benefit to you is the same as the benefit you always have when opening connections on the fly: it's easier to write the inner code without having to be aware of transactions or how to recover from errors halfway.

Comment: Not true. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN under transaction support. My question is if the enlist action is too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The recommendation is to use a connection Open/Close for each statement.

Without seeing that comment in context, I'm guessing this recommendation is because of what you said: creating and destroying a `SqlConnection` objects does not mean you are creating and destroying network connections.

I think the motive behind "use one for each statement" is to just not worry about trying to be efficient about when you create `SqlConnection` objects. Don't go out of your way to keep one alive and pass it around all throughout your code thinking you are avoiding tearing down a network connection. There's just no point.

In your example, it won't really make a difference. You can use the same `SqlConnection` object for each query if you'd like, as long as you are making them sequentially and not in parallel. It's probably even *slightly* more efficient since you save the computational time of creating an `SqlConnection` object. But that saved time will likely not even be noticeable.

Comment: Is it true though. In the docs, it's mentioned that when in a transaction, if the connection related to the transaction is not available, then another connection enlists to it. I'm talking about multi statement transactions, not atomic statements. Doesn't that enlistment cost?

Comment: Right. I'm talking about multi-statement transactions too. You can either 1. Create a new `SqlConnection` for each statement, and `Close` each one before you start the next, or 2. Use the same `SqlConnection` for each statement. Both ways will use the same network connection.

Comment: The only reason a second actual network connection would be used (and a switch to a distributed transaction) is if you created a new `SqlConnection` object without disposing the previous one. This is shown in [the example in the documentation for `TransactionScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Comment: I'm talking about unavailable sql connections. Check my last comment under the question.

Comment: That documentation you linked to says that it will keep a connection open when the transaction starts and use that unless it's not available. The only reason it wouldn't be available is if you are creating a second `SqlConnection` object without disposing the first.

Comment: Is it not possible that some other thread picked the connection? Especially during peak times, it could be that could be the case and at worst a new connection will need to be added to the pull, keeping the transaction open more than it should be?

Comment: The documentation says, "Connections are drawn from the pool and *assigned based on transaction context*." Then later, "When a connection is closed, it is released back into the pool and *into the appropriate subdivision based on its transaction context*." So it knows which connection is for which transaction and assigns connections based on the transaction context needed. It doesn't explicitly say it, but that implies that it will not use a connection known to be in a an open transaction for a thread that is not in that transaction.