# What exactly is connection enlistment in C#

Tags: c#, transactions

As a follow up to [Multiple connections to the same DB in the same TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770329/multiple-connections-to-the-same-db-in-the-same-transactionscope), I'm trying to find what is meant exactly by the following [in this guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> Connections are drawn from the pool and assigned based on transaction
> context. Unless Enlist=false is specified in the connection string,
> the connection pool makes sure that the connection is enlisted in the
> Current context. When a connection is closed and returned to the pool
> with an enlisted System.Transactions transaction, it is set aside in
> such a way that the next request for that connection pool with the
> same System.Transactions transaction will return the same connection
> if it is available.

In another section it's mentioned that

> Connections are drawn from the pool and assigned based on transaction context.
>
> When a connection is closed, it is released back into the pool and into the appropriate subdivision based on its transaction context.

Based on the above, I've got two questions:

1. Is it safe to assume that an enlisted connection, will NEVER be used in another transaction as long as the transaction exists, even though it's closed? Is there any documentation explaining if our assumptions that this is so?
2. How can a connection NOT be available if it is only used in the enlisted transaction? What can be the case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that an enlisted connection, will NEVER be used
>   in another transaction as long as the transaction exists, even though
>   it's closed?

Yes.

> Is there any documentation explaining if our assumptions that this is so?

You quoted it: "Connections are drawn from the pool and assigned based on transaction context."

> How can a connection NOT be available if it is only used in the enlisted transaction? What can be the case for this?

It can be in-use.  eg in a TransactionScope:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
   con.Open();
   using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(...))  
   {
     con2.Open(); //con is not available, as it's open and in-use so a new connection will be opened and enlisted
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought so too. I'm wondering what would happen if the two connections refer to the same connection string in your example.

Comment: There's no difference if they use the same connection string or not, since there's no available pooled connection.  If they used different connection strings, then you would always get two different connections, even if the first was available.